# linux file descriptors confusion

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

Why does this not work?

The way I see it you open fd 3 and its sent to dev nul.

Then later your route fd 3 to fd 2.

What I am trying to accomplish is using fd 3 in my scripts as a standard info that default pipes to the void but if needed can be routed to stderr or a file for inspection.

MyScript.bash

```
exec 3>/dev/null
echo spo >&3
```

This echos nothing to stderr:

```
./MyScript.bash 3>&2
```

Comment: I would write an info function and use a variable as a flag which determines whether it writes, rather than send everything to `/dev/null`. Also I prefer not using `exec` for redirection. It can be error prone if your script gets too complicated, because what the exec applies to can be very context-sensitive, and you have to handle closing any opened fds manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you *run* your script, the shell attaches file descriptor 3 to stderr.

However, *within* your script, it uses `exec` to send file descriptor 3 data to the bit bucket, basically overriding what you did when running the script.

One way around this is to not do the redirection at the time of starting your script. Instead pass an optional parameter with the file you want to use:

```
./MyScript               # with no parameter
./MyScript /tmp/xyzzy    # with a parameter
```

and then have your script take total control:

```
fd3file=/dev/null
if [[ "$1" != "" ]] ; then
    fd3file="$1"
fi
exec 3>${fd3file}
```

It doesn't need to use a parameter, you could use *any* source of information such as an environment variable, configuration file entry or so forth. The basic premise stands however - let the script make the decision.

Now you _can do this at multiple layers (shell and script redirection) by taking advantage of the fact that:

- if you try to duplicate a file descriptor for output that isn't actually open, that's considered a redirection error; and
- `exec` will fail with return code 1 if a redirection error occurs.

The following script shows this in action. It tries to duplicate `fd 3` onto `fd 4` and detects failure. Failure means `fd 3` wasn't open so we then hook it up to `/dev/null`. Success means it was open so we leave it alone since the user has already connected it to something:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Try and duplicate fd 3 (without ugly error message)

( exec 4>&3 ) 2>/dev/null

# Figure out whether fd3 was open.

if [[ $? -eq 1 ]] ; then
    # It was not open so we need redirect.

    echo 'redirect failed, need to exec 3>/dev/null'
    exec 3>/dev/null
else
    # It was, open so we leave fd3 alone (and close fd4 duplicate).

    echo 'redirect worked, leave fd3 alone'
    exec 4>-
fi

echo 'fd3 content' >&3
```

The following transcript shows it in action. First, the one without shell-based redirection which causes the script to hook up `fd 3` to `/dev/null`:

```
pax> ./qq.sh
redirect failed, need to exec 3>/dev/null

pax> cat qq
cat: qq: No such file or directory
```

Next, the one *with* shell-based redirection (to `qq`) which leaves `fd 3` alone, and you can then see that the redirection to `qq` has happened:

```
pax> ./qq.sh 3>qq
redirect worked, leave fd3 alone

pax> cat qq
fd3 content
```

Comment: that makes sense! I guess I can not accomplish what I want! It seems if I don`t have the fd declared in the script and pipe to it it is an error but if I declare the fd it will override my redirect from the command line!

Comment: @James, there's _many_ ways around problems, I updated the answer with one.

Comment: so many options in Bash especially. This is exactly what I just ended up doing, ty for the affirmation.

Comment: @James, I've also added a way that works with both levels of redirection (shell and script) if you want to go that way. It's not something I'd recommend for the faint of heart but it will work. Please just don't release it on an unsuspecting world without documentation :-)